# Php split pdf file

Tags: php, pdf, split

How can I split pdf file? I tried use FPDI, but pdf file must have version 1.4. Are there any other FREE solutions in php for split pdf by pages and save each page to seperate file? Really dont see any other free solution.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For split pdf by pages you can use http://pdfparser.org/ and for save each page to seperate file https://mpdf.github.io/

Comment: Is pdfparser free tool? And there is function getText() , but how can I get html from page? Thanks!

Comment: Of course pdfparser is open source. if you want to convert pdf to html used http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdftohtml/ or xpdf.

Answer (score 0):

Try PDFtk Server. It is a command-line tool which you can execute from a PHP script. It allows many different kinds of PDF manipulation, like splitting a document into smaller pieces. PDFtk is free.

Example command-line use:

```
pdftk document.pdf burst
```